# How to make 3D objects the children of hair strands?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, animation-nodes

I saw this inspirational thread [Access hair child strands (animation nodes)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101184/access-hair-child-strands-animation-nodes?rq=1)

From there, an idea suddenly popped into my head — how about making grass leaves the children of hair strands. Is that possible? I don't know how to do it. 
I thought hair strands can easily get lost inside leaves and won't be noticeable. As children, grass leaves can mimic behaviour of their parents, namely the hair strands.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you you would like to use Animation Nodes as opposed to a normal particle system? Can you provide me details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: When I first saw your works with strands like bending and waving them, I thought that you could use your waves to form the edges of fern as in photo here. https://finefoliage.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/img_9276-cr2.jpg

Comment: But then I next thought about grass and wonder if that is possible with Animation Nodes. For learning purpose only, I'd to see how to CHILD any object to hair strands. I imagine grass as the easiest shapes. When I learn to child grass to hair strand, I will next ask another question how to furl or curl the edges of leaves.

Comment: Btw, I haven't yet mastered particle system, and I am only learning about it this week.

Comment: Ok, sure. Will add an answer later today or tomorrow.

Comment: There is no hurry, Omar. Take all the time. I appreciate what you are doing.

Comment: It seems python access to particles in blender is now [broken](https://developer.blender.org/T58792). We will have to fix that first before we can use it. So I will answer your question once this is fixed.

Comment: No worries and I am in no great hurry. So, take all the time you want. As you are a genius at mathematics and programming, I bet you love problems that mean challenges and make you want to solve them. Good luck. =)